# Select from Two tables last name first name and avg salary in descending order by last name

Tags: mysql, sql

**Actor table**

[image]

**Castings table**

[image]

I am new to SQL and am stuck on a problem I am working on. I am wanting to display the last name, first name and avg salary of an actor. The salary and the actor's name is in two different tables. , Also I would like to display the results in descending order according to the actors last name. Here is what I have written up but I cannot get it to compile correctly. I have provided a screenshot of what I have so far.

[image]

Comment: Could you provide your tables info? you use `JOIN` but didn't use `on`

Comment: sure one second please.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error related to only\_full\_group\_by when executing a query in MySql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34115174/error-related-to-only-full-group-by-when-executing-a-query-in-mysql)

Comment: Add picture directly and avoid post them just as a link

Comment: Definitely not a duplicate, @D-Shih I have revised and added my actor and castings table

Comment: Add `group by a.lname, fname ` before `order by ` clause.

Comment: @lucumt please don't encourage the provision of pictures where raw, formatted text would do just as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `JOIN` but didn't use `on` to connect two table, from your tables you might use `actorID` columns to be the connected condition.

when you use an aggregate function you might use non-aggregate columns in `group by`

```
SELECT a.lname,a.fname,AVG(c.salary)
FROM Actor a 
JOIN Castings c on a.actorID = c.actorID 
group by a.lname,a.fname
order by a.lname desc
```

Here is a link talking about [JOIN](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-join/)

Comment: thank you for your help. This worked great. I was hoping you could help with one more thing. I am trying to use a Subquery where I can select the salary for an actor where I "forgot" their actorId but know there name. Anything I try gives me syntax errors

Comment: SELECT salary
FROM Castings 
WHERE salary = (SELECT fname 
               FROM Actor
               WHERE fname = 'Paul');

Comment: I think ou need to use `join` rather than subquery `SELECT a.lname,a.fname,c.salary
FROM Actor a 
JOIN Castings c on a.actorID = c.actorID 
WHERE a.fname = 'Paul'
`